# Hive max columns per table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Does anybody knows limitation for maximum nuber columns per table in Hive?
Something like in Oracle Database it was 1000 columns per table. 
I tried to create table with 5000 columns in Hive and didn't get any error.
May be it is any limitation for HiveQL script length limit (maybe like 65536 bytes)

Thanks